# Selectively predict time series

Tags: regression, time-series, sampling

Say I have a time series ${y}$ and a number of features $f_1, f_2, ...$. Most of the time, it is hard to predict ${y}$, but in some scenarios I can get good results. How do I set up the model, and how do I discover when to predict("bet") on the next value of $y$? For example, how can I differentiate between needing better features, and unpredictability of the time series at certain occasions?

Comment: At a minimum, you define a metric and use appropriate predictive methods to evaluate the reliability of the predictions (or are they forecasts? You allude to the "next" value of $y$, which isn't a prediction problem.)

Comment: What do you mean, it's not a prediction problem? You observe everything at time t, try to predict y(t+1). What is it then, if not prediction?

Comment: Look at what satistical arbitrage traders do: backtest.

Answer (score 1):

One way in which you can address this problem is by using a [GARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) model. What you seem to be describing is a case of heteroskedasticity, in which the variance of the error in the regression varies across time. Thus, in some period, the variability might be low (and thus the reliability of the model would be high), and in other periods the variability might be high (making $y$ more "erratic").

A GARCH model allows you to:

- Get coefficients and standard errors for your main model that take into account this heteroskedasticity
- Produce a model for the variance itself (see the third equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH)), so that you will know if the variance for the period you're interested in predicting is high or low.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to predict y separately from its past values + each feature in turns and then use some sort of averaging of the separate point forecasts to get an overall point forecast? Or group the features by functional domains and then predict y from its past values plus all features in a given domain, followed by some sort of averaging of point forecasts across functional domains?